# Change only the negative values in a column keeping all other columns in R

Tags: r

Newbie to R here.

I have a column that has both negative and positive numbers. I want to change all the negative numbers to positive as they have been incorrectly assigned as negative. How can I do this while keeping all the other columns in the dataframe?

using df_Test <- lapply(df$column, abs) returns just a list but I would like to either replace the column with only absolute values or create a new column with the absolute values.

I've been trying every which way for an hour and it's driving me mad. Worth noting that my dataframe is not only numeric. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may just call `abs()` on the particular column directly:

```
df_Test <- df
df_Test$column <- abs(df_Test$column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try either approach below

```
sign(df)*df
```

or

```
abs(df)
```

which gives

```
           x          y
1  0.6264538 1.51178117
2  0.1836433 0.38984324
3  0.8356286 0.62124058
4  1.5952808 2.21469989
5  0.3295078 1.12493092
6  0.8204684 0.04493361
7  0.4874291 0.01619026
8  0.7383247 0.94383621
9  0.5757814 0.82122120
10 0.3053884 0.59390132
```

**Dummy Data**

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(-0.626453810742332, 0.183643324222082, -0.835628612410047, 
1.59528080213779, 0.329507771815361, -0.820468384118015, 0.487429052428485,
0.738324705129217, 0.575781351653492, -0.305388387156356), y = c(1.51178116845085,
0.389843236411431, -0.621240580541804, -2.2146998871775, 1.12493091814311,
-0.0449336090152309, -0.0161902630989461, 0.943836210685299,
0.821221195098089, 0.593901321217509)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-10L))
```